# Can I use low voltage twisted doorbell wire in wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, low-voltage, doorbell

I am running new bell wire and the low voltage 20/2 bell wire I got is twisted with no sheathing (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-100-ft-20-2-Twisted-CU-Bell-Wire-56750023/205717549)

I can't seem to find any specs on if this is allowed to be used in wall or not.

I was a little concerned since there is no sheathing and wasn't sure if that was a but no no when running wiring in wall.

Comment: Think besides not having low voltage and high voltage in the same junction boxes, code does not care that much for low voltage stuff.  You are allowed to do almost anything with it,

Comment: That's what I thought as well - mind posting answer and I'll give you credit

Comment: Seriously consider running at least three conductor, someday you may need it for a smart doorbell button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wire is fine for running in a wall. The determining factor is that it will be carrying low voltage...so you're ok.  As an aside, there are many useful and slick wireless doorbell options now that you may want to consider.